# Forgotten iPhone 5S password, but the password is stored in notes

Tags: password, iphone

I cannot remember the password for my iPhone 5S. The password is written in the Notes app on my phone.

Touch ID is not an option because it's not working (I haven't set it up).

Is there any way I can retrieve the password?

Comment: Access your notes from iCloud.com incase you had the notes synced

Answer (score 1):

You can access Notes on icloud.com and on any 10.9 Mac that was synced to your iCloud account.